# What happens to my answer when the question is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

Let's say I answer a question. And there are upvotes for my answer (so, I get reputation points for my answer). Now, the question is deleted. What happens to my answer and what happens to the reputation points I earned?

Comment: TL;DR: answer will be deleted as well, and reputation will be lost (unless it's 60 days or older and scoring 3 or more).

Comment: Do note that question author can't delete it once an answer is upvoted. It can only be deleted by others. So those cases are pretty rare. :)

Comment: ...and usually mean that the question was deleted for moderation reasons rather than voluntarily.